# Show line number in WebStorm console using Node.js

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm

I have warnings and errors in my Node.js app server but I can't figure out where it is in my code.

I use WebStorm 2017.2.4 and run Node.js by using the WebStorm's integrated 'Run'. Everything is shown in the WebStorm console so everything is fine but I don't have the line number. For example, if I write `console.log('hello')` the console will show `hello` without the line number.

How can I change that?

Answer (score 2):

Maye this URL can help you out:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/running-and-debugging-node-js.html

Instead you can also log the linenumber together with the "hello" but I'd recommend using proper debugging as it's a lot more effective.

Comment: Thanks for the link but I couldn't find how to add the line number. I'm so surprised it's not even by default!

Comment: You could log it by adding a line number to your console.log.

However logs aren't really supposed to be used for debugging and you should try to use the debugging tools instead.

It might take some "get used to" but will be very rewarding in the end.

Basically you would add a breakpoint to before the location(s) where you expect your code to have a bug. From that point you will go tru the code executing line by line to find out where your bug is at

Comment: Thanks for your comment and I will definitely start using breakpoints... unfortunately I can't accept this answer because it doesn't answer my question.